# VBA random row from all max values in a Range

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first post, please let me know if anything can be clarified.

I'm trying to set up a simple vocabulary sheet in Excel.

The idea is to have 3 Sheets, one will show language A and ask for Answer in language B,
the other one will do it the other way around, and the last sheet is the list of all words in the 2 languages.

The WordList Sheet has 4 columns (Nr., Lang.A, Lang.B, Rating) and here my problem starts.

Right now I have set it up that on the "LanguageSheet" a word from the list is shown, you can type in the answer and I have a Macro for .OnKey which triggers when hitting the Enter key (~).

If the answer is correct it directly reduces the value of Column "Rating" on the "Wordlist" sheet in this row by 1 and will chose a new word. 
If the answer is wrong you can press one of two buttons "my answer was right" if there was just a typo or something, or "my answer was wrong" clicking the "right button" will also reduce the "rating" value by 1 and chose a new word, clicking the "wrong button" will increase the "rating" by 1 and chose a new word.

Right now I have two versions of this xls, one version just chose a random word of the list, version 2 is looking for the maximum value in the Rating and shows the word with the max value.

In general version 2 is closer to what I want to achieve but it has some problems right now.

It always gives me the first Word in the list with the highest Rating, normally there are several words with the same high rating.
If the chosen word is entered wrong it will show the same word again because its "rating" value increased again this happens until the rating is lower than some others.

**My Goal:** Is to check the "Rating" Column and give me a random feedback of one of all the words with the highest rating e.g. 15 Words have the Rating 5 then give me back a random word of this 15 not just the first one. This would be better than the current version but still not ideal because if there is one word with a higher rating then all others this word will repeated over and over again until the rating is lower. This option would be ok if it can be avoided that one word repeats immediately.

So another idea is to look for the 10 (or how much ever) highest Rating words (does not need to be the same rating e.g. 6,6,5,4,... an so on) and ask them in a random order but each word just once. after all words are answered doesn't matter if right or wrong it will again choose the 10 highest rating words and so on. But also here it should not just choose the first 10 words with the highest rating (in case of same rating value) it should choose them randomly among all the words with the same rating.

So this was a lot of text please see what I have so far as Macro for the `OnKey` which works:

```
Public sh As Worksheet, nr As Long, Mx As Long, rw As Long, Rng As Range

Option Explicit

Public Sub SetOnkey()

Application.OnKey "~", "UseOnkey"

End Sub
Public Sub UseOnkey()

If ActiveSheet Is Sheet3 Then

    If Range("C16") = "Right!" Then

        sh.Range("F" & rw).Value = sh.Range("F" & rw).Value - 1

        Cells(15, 3).Clear
        Cells(15, 3).Font.Size = 48

        Set Rng = sh.Range("F2:F351")   
        Mx = WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng)
        rw = WorksheetFunction.Match(Mx, Rng, 0) + Rng.Row - 1

        Range("C5") = sh.Range("D" & rw)

     End If

 ElseIf ActiveSheet Is Sheet1 Then

    If Range("C16") = "Right!" Then

        sh.Range("F" & rw).Value = sh.Range("F" & rw).Value - 1

        Cells(15, 3).Clear
        Cells(15, 3).Font.Size = 48

        Set Rng = sh.Range("F2:F351")   
        Mx = WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng)
        rw = WorksheetFunction.Match(Mx, Rng, 0) + Rng.Row - 1

        Range("C5") = sh.Range("B" & rw)

    End If


End If
End Sub

Public Sub UnsetOnkey()

Application.OnKey "~"

End Sub
```

Further I have this for the buttons:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Set sh = Sheets(3) 

Set Rng = sh.Range("F2:F351")   
    Mx = WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng)
    rw = WorksheetFunction.Match(Mx, Rng, 0) + Rng.Row - 1

    Range("C5") = sh.Range("D" & rw)

    Cells(15, 3).Clear
    Cells(15, 3).Font.Size = 48
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    sh.Range("F" & rw).Value = sh.Range("F" & rw).Value - 1

    Cells(15, 3).Clear
    Cells(15, 3).Font.Size = 48

    Set Rng = sh.Range("F2:F351")   
    Mx = WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng)
    rw = WorksheetFunction.Match(Mx, Rng, 0) + Rng.Row - 1

    Range("C5") = sh.Range("D" & rw)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    sh.Range("F" & rw).Value = sh.Range("F" & rw).Value + 1

    Cells(15, 3).Clear
    Cells(15, 3).Font.Size = 48

    Set Rng = sh.Range("F2:F351")   
    Mx = WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng)
    rw = WorksheetFunction.Match(Mx, Rng, 0) + Rng.Row - 1

    Range("C5") = sh.Range("D" & rw)


End Sub
```

Unfortunately I'm not very skilled in this I just have some basic understanding how to do things.

I tried to explain it as detailed as possible if any open questions or I need to change anything please let me know.

Comment: Why don't you use the Worksheet_Change event to trigger action? The On_Key event isn't meant for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No doubt about it, your question is both massive and manifold. Please, for the future, formulate questions so that they can be answered concisely. I will tackle the problem of avoiding repetitions and suggest you create a function like this:-

```
Function WasAsked(NextWord As String) As Boolean
    ' 014
    ' this code requires a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'

    Static Dict As Scripting.Dictionary

    If Dict Is Nothing Then Set Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    With Dict
        If .Exists(NextWord) Then
            WasAsked = True
        Else
            .Add NextWord, 0
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

The idea is that you create a way to suggest a word (that's another subject, for another question). Then you ask this function if the word was asked before. If the function returns True (*WasAsked = True*) your other function selects another word and submits it. Your code might look like this:-

```
Dim NextWord As String
Dim SkipWord As Boolean

Do 
    NextWord = SuggestAWord()          ' a function that returns a new word
    SkipWord = WasAsked(NextWord)
Loop While SkipWord
```

The function `WasAsked` creates a dictionary and adds each asked word to it. This dictionary remains in memory for the duration of the session. Therefore no repeats can be asked until Excel is shut down (or crashes). You can test the function with this code.

```
Private Sub TestWasAsked()
    Debug.Print WasAsked("Lion")
End Sub
```

The first time it will return False, every time after that True. Remember to checkmark the reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime in the list of references in VBE's Tools menu. Change the parameter ("Lion") to add more words to the dictionary.

I draw your attention to this line of code in the function.

```
.Add NextWord, 0
```

The Dictionary is designed as a dictionary, meaning a word is matched with info associated with that word, for example the translation into another language, or a name and telephone number, an item and a price. At present my function uses only half its capability- its ability to search. The associated value the above code is 0. In the future you may like to record the translation and then possibly use the same dictionary to ask about the same words in the other language. - Just saying :-)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, and thank you for your tips and your support. I need to dig in to the topics you mentioned here but I think I can figure it out and build something like you suggested.